# Why PySpark dropDuplicates and Join gives ODD results

Tags: python, pyspark, left-join, drop-duplicates

PySpark gives me little odd results after dropDuplicates and join data-sets. The situation is there are two very large dataset: one with people's ID and some variables and second one with their region_code

first dataset:

```
ID|VAR1|VAR2|VAR3|VAR4|VAR5|
1|-----|----|---|---|----|
2|-----|----|---|---|----|
3|-----|----|---|---|----|
4|-----|----|---|---|----|
```

second dataset:

```
ID|region_code|
1|7|
2|5|
1|9|
4|7|
```

the result which I'm getting after following code is:

```
file_1 = file_1.dropDuplicates(["ID"])
file_2 = file_2.dropDuplicate(["ID"])
file_2.filter(filter("ID == '1'").show()

ID|region_code|
1|7|
```

After joining the files I'm expecting:

```
merge_file = file_1.join(file_2, "ID", "left")

ID|VAR1|VAR2|VAR3|VAR4|VAR5|region_code|
1|-----|----|---|---|----|7|
2|-----|----|---|---|----|5|
3|-----|----|---|---|----|null|
4|-----|----|---|---|----|7|
```

but I got:

```
merge_file.filter("ID == '1'").show()

ID|VAR1|VAR2|VAR3|VAR4|VAR5|region_code|
1|-----|----|---|---|----|9|
```

I'm very curious about these strange results.

Comment: I'm not sure `dropDuplicates` is the function you're looking for here.  In your example `ID == 1` has two associated regions.  Dropping duplicate `ID` would arbitrarily select a region for each `ID` then drop the others, which isn't a reliable behavior.

Comment: Is your suggestion to use `file_2.dropDuplicates(["ID", "region_code"])` ? and why first applied filter on file_2 gives after dropDuplicates gives 
`ID|region_code|
1|7|`

Answer (score 0):

`pyspark` is a lazy interpreter.  Your code is only executed when you call an action (i.e. `show()`, `count()` etc.). In your code example you are creating `file_2`.  Instead of thinking of `file_2` as an object living in memory, `file_2` is really just a set of instructions that tells the `pyspark` engine the processing steps.  When you call `file_2.filter(filter("ID == '1'").show()` those instructions are being executed (including `dropDuplicates()`) to generate the output.

When you are creating `merge_file` you are referencing the processing steps for `file_2`, which could be evaluated differently than your previous example.  There is no guarantee that `dropDuplicates()` will drop the same rows every time because of the lazy execution of `pyspark`.  This is why you are getting different results between the two DataFrames.

This is also why I would suggest you think about your data and what you want to accomplish with your `merge` because `dropDuplicates()` is not a reliable method if the relationship between `ID` and `region` is important.

Comment: Thank you @vealkind for the explanation, which function for dropping duplicated records from file_2, would you recommend? I want to achieve only one record per ID in file_2.

Comment: You could do the following: `file_2.groupby(func.col("ID")).agg(func.collect_set(func.col("region_code")).alias("arr_region"))`, which will create one record per `ID` that will contain an array of all distinct `region_name` associated with the `ID` then perform your `merge`.